# angularjs ui-validate does not work for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angularjs ui-validate from ui-utils but it does not work.
The `ui-utils.js` is loaded in the page but when I debug I can not see any stop inside the directive. This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-cool input" ng-model="name"
           name="name" placeholder="Introduce la matricula" required
           ng-pattern="/(\d{4}[\D\w]{3}|[\D\w]{1,2}\d{4}[\D\\w]{2})/"
           ui-validate="{blacklist : 'notBlackListed($value)' }"/>
   <span ng-show="warehouseForm.name.$error.pattern">Formato de matricula incorrecto. Formato valido: 1111XXX</span></div>
```

and the function in my controller (it is a copy of an example)

```
var notBlackListed = function (value) {
            var blacklist = ['bad@domain.com', 'verybad@domain.com'];
            return blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
        };
```

I can't get it to work, so what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function "notBlackListed" must be visible in $scope, not in "private" scope of the controller so change to:

```
    $scope.notBlackListed = function (value) {
        var blacklist = ['bad@domain.com', 'verybad@domain.com'];
        return blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
    };
```

this is an old question, but may help others.